# <li> tag with wrapping text is causing its parent div to expand in width?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Would like some clarification on why this happens.

I have a parent div that is set to have `width:70%`

Inside the parent div, I have two more divs that are side by side. The left div has `width:15%`, while the right div has no class. As I expect, the left div is 15% of the width of the parent div.

However, when I add an `<li>` tag with so much text in it that the text wraps onto the next line, it seems like the left div shrinks in width. It is narrower than 15% width of the parent div.

Changing `width: 15%` to `min-width: 15%` fixes the issue, but I would like to know why.

```css
body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white;
  /* Change my color to yellow */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}

.left {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
      <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://playcode.io/1647378

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the content of left

```html
<style>

    body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white;
  /* Change my color to yellow */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}

.left {
    width: 15%;
}

.list {
    width: 85%;
} 
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        <li>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

. Since the list div do not have a specified width, it takes all the free space ignoring width property of left.

Comment: If the list div doesn't have a specified width, why ignore the width property of the left div? Shouldn't it take up all the remaining free space while honoring the left's width property?

Comment: nah it probably has occupying other's land in blood.
Although it occupies because of no content in that width.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white;
  /* Change my color to yellow */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.parent {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: white;
}

.left {
  width: 15%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="left">
          Left
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis velit et similique quo aut ea, in sunt eum dolorem unde sit non tenetur reiciendis eaque, sapiente explicabo facilis, doloremque eius.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus et explicabo suscipit excepturi ipsum voluptatem. Mollitia, adipisci. Quae, sit deleniti! Nisi vitae dolorum voluptate esse vel consectetur deserunt repellat fuga!</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You have set display: flex; in the parent element;, This allows the child elements in the parent element to adjust their own size as needed. Even if you set a fixed width for the left element, it may still change in case of resizing the parent element